# Is there a way to write content that screen readers will ignore?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I've just been working on a page which needs to be accessible to both sighted and visually impaired users. Some elements of the content, just by the nature of relating only to visual elements, simply do not apply to people using screen readers. For example, a link opens an audio-visual presentation in a new window, but due to circumstances beyond my control, the window is awkwardly resized, so there's a message saying that you should resize the window so you can see everything better. Obviously this is useless information to someone who can't see it anyway.

Is there an accepted way to make screen readers ignore some content?

Comment: "which needs to be accessible to both sighted and visually impaired users" - unfortunately all webmasters don't realize that this applies to all public pages as well :-/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Halfway through writing the question I remembered where to look.

CSS can do this:

```
<span class="dontRead">Screen readers shouldn't read this</span>

.dontRead {
    speak: none;
}
```

Comment: Probably goes without saying, but <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." media="aural" /> also improves targeting for screen readers.

Comment: Yet another time that i wish i could mod comments up. thanks for that tip. good question and answer too :) +1 to alll

Comment: Does this actually work with any known screenreader? My understanding is that screenreaders ignore this outright, so it will have no effect. Keep in mind that screenreaders are, despite the name, not strictly "aural" in their presentation; many also output via Braille.

Comment: This doesn't work with JAWS. Using this does not work.

Answer (score 46):

Actually the correct way of doing this is by using [the ARIA attribute `aria-hidden="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden).
Like this:

```
<button type="button">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon">&gt;</span>
  <span class="hide">Go!</span>
</button>
```

By doing this you hide the > character so screen-readers won't read "right angle bracket", and instead read "Go!". Sighted users will only see > if you hide the content in the .hide class visually.
Like this:

```
.hide{
  position: absolute;
  left:-999em;
}
```

The ARIA role `presentation` is for "normalizing" semantic meaning, like for example a `<table>` with `role="presentation"` won't be read as table content and will be just plain text.

If you want an image not to be read you can put in empty `alt` text like this:

```
<img src="decorative-flower.jpg" alt=""/>
```

..or if it's an `<svg>` omit the `<title>` and `<description>`

```
<svg>
  <!-- <title>Remove this line</title> -->
  <!-- <description> Remove this too..</description> -->
</svg>
```

I have noticed in some rare situations some screen-readers have still read the empty alt images, so you could use `aria-hidden="true"` here as well.

CSS' speak property is not supported at this point, and the same goes for the link attribute media="aural".

Comment: This is the correct answer, `aria-hidden` is well supported and was created for the exact purpose of e.g. hiding text from a screen-reader whilte preserving it on the screen. https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/

Comment: this doesn't seem like the right answer .. what about ::before and ::after? necessitating use case: <span aria-hidden="true">read this</span> with span::before { content: 'but don-t read this' }

Comment: Some screen-readers read text from the `content:` property and some screen-readers don't. In either case all screen-readers will ignore content that's inside a DOM object with `aria-hidden="true"` attribute. If you use a pseudo element like `:before` of `::after` they are still part of that DOM object and will be ignored if the "parent" has `aria-hidden="true"`. Like `<span aria-hidden="true">Will be ignored</span` `span::before{content:'Will also be ignored';}`.

Answer (score 6):

check for this

```
<h1 role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Some text that screen readers will ignore </h1>
```

because of **role="presentation"** and **tabindex="-1"** screen reader will ignore above tag.

i checked this on ie8 and firefox 3.5 it is working with JAWS screen reader.

Comment: This actually only overrides the implicit role of `heading` and makes the <h1> not focusable (which it isn't to begin with). A screen-reader would still read this however. Use `aria-hidden="true"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has those aural properties, but as they aren't implemented anywhere they are completely useless.

Comment: Screen readers never see the CSS - they simply look at what the browser (IE, or recent versions of Firefox) exposes through its accessibility interface, and browsers don't recognise aural styles :-(

It's a common misconception that screenreaders are a kind of browser. In reality, they are operating system extensions, designed to read the output of many existing programs.

(I noticed the other year that most of the bug reports on the website for Jaws, the most widely-used screenreader, related to its use with Excel and Word rather than web browsers, though this may have changed by now.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with hiding specific pieces of information from users of assistive technologies is that it assumes they are using your software alone in some dark room, which simply not a safe assumption. Many users of assistive technology collaborate closely with other users (to whom this information would be relevant), and a few very fortunate ones even have assistants. You would be wise to de-emphasize or under-prioritize this content for them instead by placing it later in the document somehow.