# How to write content in html that screen readers will ignore but will be visible in page

Tags: html, accessibility, web

This is the same question as [Is there a way to write content that screen readers will ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672156/is-there-a-way-to-write-content-that-screen-readers-will-ignore)

But given solution in above link **speak: none;** is not working.

Please guide me about this.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you want to do this? Knowing what you are trying to do may help come up with an example. (Also, be careful not to assume that all screen reader users are totally blind; some partially sighted or low vision users may use a combination of magnification and/or screenreaders).

Comment: check for this 

    <h1 role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Some text that screen readers will ignore </h1>

because of **role="presentation"** and **tabindex="-1"** screen reader will ignore above tag.

i checked this on ie8 and firefox 3.5 it is working with JAWS screen reader.

Comment: I'm still curious why you'd want to do this in the first place. role=presentation was mainly aimed at tables that were used for layout; and says to the screenreader: the content is still important, just ignore the fact that it's a table - treat it as plain content, don't tell the user about rows/cols. So it doesn't mean to ignore the whole thing completely. You may get mixed results if you use it for something else.

Comment: There are plenty of valid reasons why you want content to be ignored by screen readers. One example would be a series of steps, 1-5, and if the user is currently on step 3, you don't want to confuse them by reading out previous steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aria-hidden="true" on the content and it will appear but be ignored by the screen reader. Please beware that any tab focus sable elements inside the content will be treated differently by different browsers and may be visible to a screen reader.