# HTML5 outline and an "Unsupported Browser" message?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

Im looking at our site with an HTML5 outliner tool and trying to improve its structure. Ive made sure we only have one  element, Ive added headings to untitled sections, etc.

We have a "Unsupported Browser" message thats in the HTML but hidden if your browser is supported. Is there a way I can mark this up so screen readers and search engines will know to ignore it? Maybe it would have been better to insert this with JavaScript when needed but this isnt an option at this stage of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough yes there is a great way to do this. It's a little know [CSS speak attribute](http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/speak.php) which can be used in the following way:

```
<span class="dontRead">Screen readers shouldn't read this</span>

.dontRead {
    speak: none;
}
```

References:

[Is there a way to write content that screen readers will ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/672156/773263)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css_ref_aural.asp