# How to ignore decorative text for accessibility reasons

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to find out a way of ignoring decorative text similar to ignoring decorative images using an empty `alt`.

Example:

```html
<!-- This is decorative image -->
<img src="example.jpg" alt="">

<!-- This should be decorative text or element -->
<div>
   Some decorative text line
   <div>
      Another decorative text line
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS is useless.

`aria-hidden` is - “indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to **any** user as implemented by the author” - so it's not an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to write content that screen readers will ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672156/is-there-a-way-to-write-content-that-screen-readers-will-ignore)

Comment: @Anodyne No, there's no answer there, but thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of doing this is by using `aria-hidden="true"`, period.

I agree with you in your quoting of the [W3C Spec for Aria-Hidden](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) reading:

> not visible or perceivable to ***any*** user...

But if you keep reading further, you will see:

> Authors **MAY**, with caution, use aria-hidden to hide visibly rendered content from assistive technologies *only* if the act of hiding this content is intended to improve the experience for users of assistive technologies by removing redundant or extraneous content. Authors using aria-hidden to hide visible content from screen readers **MUST** ensure that identical or equivalent meaning and functionality is exposed to assistive technologies.

Also, another route that you could go is to convert the text content to image and then use a blank alt attribute to indicate that it is a decorative image. That may or may not be preferable depending on your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

The most important part of the documentation is the explanation

> Some assistive technologies access WAI-ARIA information directly through the DOM and not through platform accessibility supported by the browser. Authors MUST set `aria-hidden="true"` on content that is not displayed, regardless of the mechanism used to hide it. This allows assistive technologies or user agents to properly skip hidden elements in the document.

Setting `aria-hidden="true"` won't hide your element from the screen on a standard browser. This is the pragmatic solution.

The problem is that what you wan't to do will never be accessible.

As long as a text is visible on screen, a visually deficient person with partial vision will want to read what he can perceive as being a text. If you hide this perceivable text from your accessible tree, this person will not be able to achieve what other people with full vision can do.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand how `alt=""` works. Is `alt=""` a shortcut to `aria-hidden="true"` for images? for example, would `<img src="image.jpg" alt=""` be equivalent to `<img src="image.jpg" aria-hidden="true"?

Comment: `img` with an empty `alt` attribute have an implicit "presentation" role. The "presentation" role does not remove the element from the accessibility tree but removes its native semantic. See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#presentation_role_effects

Comment: But doesn't removing native semantics for `img` element will remove it from accessibility tree? If not, then what is the reason it is still remain in the accessibility tree? And another thing: if I'll use the same way on decorative text - I'll make it unenforceable by setting `tabindex` to `-1` and set `role` for `presentation`, and of course do it accordingly to the child elements if needed - would it then remain in the accessibility tree as well as img? Thanks for helping me to figure it out, Adam

Comment: `alt` is a mandatory (X)HTML attribute for img element in HTML 4.01, XHTML, HTML5, etc. Its value is either empty or some text. `aria-hidden` is an ARIA attribute: not only related to HTML but also SVG and who knows? ARIA in general helps when HTML alone isn't sufficient;something like ["First rule of ARIA is don't use ARIA (if you don't need it)"](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1). Good use of alt has always been sufficient for img. New elements, new way of doing front-end makes `aria-hidden` necessary... in other cases

Comment: @lessismore Giving the presentation role does not remove the element from the accessibility tree : for instance a table used for layout purpose must have a presentation role but its content will still be read by a screenreader like a standard `div` but not annouced as a table. For an image, the effect of giving an empty `alt` gives a default "presentation" role, so the object is not announced as being an image, and as there's no alternative content, nothing is announced.